# Why does SQL Browser service get disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an intermittent problem with a software installation package that installs our product (written using InstallShield/InstallScript).  During the process of the installation, we restart the SQL Browser Service.  Most of the time this works fine.  But occasionally - and I have not worked out how to reproduce this predictably - the service fails to restart, and I find in my "Services" manager that the service status is set to "Disabled".

Any ideas what would be causing the service to be disabled, and how to prevent it happening?

Comment: [SQL Slammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Slammer) fallout.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - on what basis do you think this might be connected to SQL Slammer?  The symptoms seem totally unrelated, and it's inconsistent.  We have none of the symptoms described, and even if we had viruses on our computers, one might at least expect the behavior to be consistent, no?

Comment: @ShaulBehr Because disabling SQL Browser would have prevented a machine from being infected by SQL Slammer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQL Server Browser Service is installed often in Disabled state (and this is what my SQL Slammer link is about, it gives the history why the Browser service is preffered to be disabled unless required). It is only required for named instances or instances listening on non-default ports. Your application installer should only restart the Browser service *if* needed, and certainly should check for a disabled service and ask an administrator permission to enable the service (ie. display a confirmation dialog) before messing with it.